# How do I create a onclick on these images to act like thumbnails and display a larger version under it?

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, thumbnails, flickr

How do I create a onclick on these images to act like thumbnails and display a larger version under it? In jQuery. I am using a flickr Api to search the images and this is where I am confused on how I would create a onclick function where if I click on one of the images that a larger version of the picture would display underneath it in the main div. Very like this jFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/99V75/light/. Thanks for any help guys.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

#main {
 background-color: red;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    right:250px;
    top:50px;   
}

div{
  padding:6px;
 }

img {
 height: 140px;
    width:260px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 70px;

}

#images {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
</head>
    
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            
            $("#button").click(function(){
                $("#images").empty();
                $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
                {
                    tags: "fire truck",
                    tagmode: "any",
                    format: "json"
                    
                }, function(data){
                    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                        $(".loadergif").remove();
                        $('<img/>').attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo('#images');
                        if(i==2) return false;
            });
            
        });
    });
        });
      
</script>
    
<button type="button" id="button">search</button>
<div id="main"</div>
<div id="images" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI - You have a script above <html> which is invalid. Also you have an unclosed div `<div id="main">/div>` and a self-closing div `<div id="images" /> </div>`. I've corrected these in the jsFiddle below as part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the onClick handler to the container since the images added are dynamic. The other issue is that you need the 'large' version of the images you're bringing in. I checked the Flickr API and it looks like you can change out the last characters of the image source to get different file sizes. Here's a link to that reference: [Flickr API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html)

Here's the code you need for the onClick handler and image source update.

```
    $('#images').on('click', 'img', function(){
        var $imgClone = $(this).clone().attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('_m.', '_b.'));
        $('#main').html($imgClone);
    });
```

And a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhdp4bhk/) to show the full code.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/k7rtq3bz/1/

This is all you need:

```
$('#images').on('click', 'img', function () {
      $('#mainImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Here is the html with slight changes and some corrections:

```
<button type="button" id="button">search</button>
<div id="main">
    <img id='mainImage' src='' />
</div>
<div id="images"></div>
```